# Bundle Identifier on the Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, identifier

I'm trying to update my app, but facing  problem with Bundle Identifier.
Older version was developed with earlier xCode, and the new one developed on latest Xcode version 4.5.2.
Later version doesn't allow me to use the same ID, which starts with a number

"5StarRingTones", it automatically converts to hyphen "-StarRingTones" and doesn't allow me to modify it, see the attached screenshot.

Which application loader will refuse to accept the update and gives error: 
"Bundle identifier: com.matrixteam.-StarRingTones differ from prior bundle identifier: com.matrixteam.5StarRingTones"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able To change it via The Info.plist.